# Xterm / Aterm takes ages to redraw the screen when changing workspace

Tags: linux, debian, xterm

This is a weird problem that i'm having, so i love xterm i've been using it for over a decade, and I've never had any problems with it. I was using it xterm fine under debian / gentoo / solaris / hp ux, i recently upgraded this system, with a AMD Ryzen 5 board, and removed the old Intel board. I completely reinstalled the operating system, the graphics card, window manager and operating system version are the same (i.e. still debian)

But whenever i switch workspaces (I'm using windowmaker) Xterm takes several seconds to redraw the xterm contents, and i use dozens of xterm windows, so it can take about 5-6 seconds to redraw all the xterm contents on the screen. I've never had this problem before, it must be some setting.

Is there some way to force it to remember the xterm contents so it doesn't redraw the entire thing unnecessarily each time you change workspaces?

I've tried other terminals too, and those also redraw the entire terminal contents from start to finish. Very slowly. So I don't think this is an xterm problem, think it's some linux xorg setting. Has anyone else come across this?

Just to add something to this, i notice the screen refresh goes really slow for the top half of the screen, then instant for the bottom half. It's almost as though it's forgotten than the terminal is maximised. When I press ALT+ENTER to full screen the window, the screen redraws instantly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to this and it seems to work. If you change the terminal font to "TrueType Fonts" then the screen redraws **instantly** when switching workspace.

This can be done by clicking on control + right click, and toggling "TrueType Fonts".

Additionally, I was able to call the xterm with the options:

```
xterm -fa 'Monospace' -fs 10
```

And this allows the terminal to redrawn instantly.

Answer (score 1):

I've bumped into the same weird problem recently (on a completely different Elbrus architecture, the common parts with your setup might be: xterm, wmaker, xorg, amdgpu, linux).

My tinkering ended with fixing up resolving on a freshly-installed host, namely adding `$(hostname)` to `127.0.0.1` line in `/etc/hosts` at least.

xterm's font remained the same bitmap one, `-rfx-serenetypewriter-medium-r-normal-*-18-180-*-*-m-*-iso10646-0400`; but the delay was gone.

Leaving this as an answer so maybe it could save some hair to another soul.

Comment: Ahhh that's interesting, i looked in my hosts file, which was on a debian system and the hostname had been set to 127.0.1.1 instead of 127.0.0.1 as a workaround for something in gnome that's horribly broken. I've removed the 127.0.1.1 entry now. Plot twist: i don't even use gnome...